# Cannot import an installed module

Tags: python, import

I cannot import a module which is installed

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google`'

It is installed as when I run

```
pip install Google
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Users/sebastianstros/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mama-bots-9Qh4WGwv-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->Google) (2.3.2.post1)
```

But importing the module I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebastianstros/PycharmProjects/mama-bots/mama_bots/bots/calendar_bot/personal_calendar_bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Google import Create_Service
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google'
```

Even though this evaluates to True:

```
print(sys.path[-1] == "/Users/sebastianstros/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mama-bots-9Qh4WGwv-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages")
```

Which is surprising to me as sys.path is a list of paths from which modules can be taken and the right hand side of the statement is the location of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is actually no package called `Google`, you may try `pip install google` for the Google libraries.

You can check all the packages from [PyPI website](https://pypi.org/).

Comment: I changed both the import and install stamenets to 'google' instead of 'Google' with no effect. I still get print the same statement saying the requirement is already satisfied and ImportError.

Comment: Do you have a `Google.py` file?

Comment: I had this issue while trying to work with Google API. I ended up using google's provided script to contact the api. The script didn't use google or Google module so it worked. You were right no Google module exists yet, I could not find google module either.